# I Can't Figure Out How to Build This Chair

Tags: modeling

I'm currently learning Blender through a book called "Blender 3D By Example". Right now I am on a section about creating chairs.

I can't figure out how to make the first chair by following the instructions. It uses almost entirely modifiers rather than box modeling. If any one could explain or show how to make this chair it would be a great help.

Here is the finished file provided with the book: [Finished File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S7u6eRhm6RI3AFvGmAZvDka-qk9yUO_u/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Instructions on the Chair]
[image: Instructions on the Chair]

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar/new to Blender you are, but if you're just starting out and looking to learn modelling through making a chair, I'd recommend watching Blender Guru's chair modelling series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf2esGA7vCc

Additionally, if you're really new to Blender, then I'd suggest his beginner tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4

Sorry, I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, though modelling is quite a subjective topic, and there are multiple ways to achieve what you want with various techniques, which are learnt over time.

Answer (score 2):

For both the chassis and the slats he is just arraying a mesh along a curve, so he's mainly using 2 modifiers: *Array* and *Curve*. You'll easily find tutorials on this matter. For the slats, it gives that (I won't use a *Mirror* modifier but it doesn't make a big difference):

- Create a bezier curve, give it the profile of the chair back along the X axis (it will make the array along curve easier to keep this axis)
- Create a plane, stretch it in *Edit* mode on the Y axis. Make sure its origin is at the same place as the curve's origin:

[image]

- Give the plane an *Array* modifier, choose the amount of instances (*Count*), enable *Relative Offset* and choose a X value of 1.2 for example, so that you keep a gap between the instances.
- Give it a *Curve* modifier, choose the bezier curve as *Object*, choose X as *Deformation* Axis:

[image]
[image]

- To change the slat length, select the bezier curve, go in *Edit* mode, select a vertex, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale:

[image]

- You can create additional vertices for the curve: go in *Edit* mode and right click > *Subdivide*. And you can give thickness to your plane with a *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

Comment: I added a bezier curve, then clicked on a verticex inside it, brought the 3d cursor to it and then set the curves origin to the 3d cursor. I then created a plane and scaled it on the x and y since it needs be 0.6 meters by on the y axis. I then added an array modifier and gave 1.2 x offset with relative offset. I then added a curve modifier and selected the bezier curve. Except the planes arent following the curve correctly. Here is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/gallery/ZaV8gcx .

Comment: please share your file, upload it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: maybe try to apply the scale and rotation of your plane, if you ever transformed it in Object mode

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=jaq2gPa9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/jaq2gPa9/)

I only scaled in edit mode, scale and rotation are all 0.

Comment: As I said it makes things easier if you align the object and curve on the X axis (in the +X direction), so rotate both object and curve in Object mode and apply their rotation and it should work

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!